youtube-dl keep size under xx MB
Is it possible to automatically limit the size of videos downloaded by youtube-dl?
Whether by downloading it partially or automatically adjusting the resolution/framerate?
Preferably I'd be able to give a size limit and the youtube link, then the commands take care of the rest. Is this doable or do I need to think of making a python script or something?

yt-dlp can do that itself. yt-dlp -S 'filesize:50M', as in man yt-dlp.
Honest remark: sounds like a bad idea. Why would you want to limit the file size of a long video to the same amount as of a short video? If you're not doing that, why not simply use yt-dlp's advanced stream selection syntax to download, e.g., the "best quality with total bitrate no higher than this and that", yt-dlp -f 'best[tbr<1000]' to get the best format combination with a cumulative average bitrate under 1000 kbps.

Note: from the man page verbiage, if no video is less than 50M this will just download whatever the smallest video is which could end up being significantly bigger than 50M

Well if it gets too ugly when reducing the size then thats that it's not really something too aggravating, I'm mostly going to use this as a quick and dirty bandage solution to a certain chatting app having made youtube embeds unbearable to view.
